# Redirect to intended URL Lumen

Tags: php, redirect, laravel, lumen

I'm building a little [Lumen](http://lumen.laravel.com) application with a simple API & Authentication.

I want to redirect the user to the intended URL and if he visits `/auth/login` by himself I want him to redirect to `/foo`.

In the [Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication) there is this function: `return redirect()->intended('/foo');`

When I use this in my route I get an error in the server log which says this:

```
[30-Apr-2015 08:39:47 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Http\Redirector::intended() in ~/Sites/lumen-test/app/Http/routes.php on line 16
```

I think this is because [Lumen](http://lumen.laravel.com) is a smaller version of [Laravel](http://laravel.com) and maybe this function isn't implemented (yet).

Comment: May be you can use named routes: http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes

Comment: The problem is, that the intended() Method does not work in Lumen :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this problem by adjusting my Middleware a little bit as well as storing the Request::path() in the session.

This is how my Middleware looks:

```
class AuthMiddleware {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        if(Auth::check()){
            return $next($request);
        } else {
            session(['path' => Request::path()]);
            return redirect('/auth/login');
        }
    }
}
```

And in my routes.php I have this route (which I will outsource to a controller asap):

```
$app->post('/auth/login', function(Request $request) {
    if (Auth::attempt($request->only('username', 'password'))){
        if($path = session('path')){
            return redirect($path);
        } else {
            return redirect('/messages');
        }
    } else {
        return redirect()->back()->with("error", "Login failed!");
    }
});
```

Thanks to [IDIR FETT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3554356/idir-fett) for suggesting the Request::path() method.
Hopefully this will help a few people that are new to 
[Lumen](http://lumen.laravel.com/), which is a great framework by the way. :)

Comment: You can avoid the use of Facades by using `$request->path()` for Request and in your constructor: `public function __construct(Guard $auth){  $this->auth = $auth; }` for Auth.

Answer (score 2):

i think you have to specify a route name in the intended method, not a URI:

```
return redirect()->intended('foo');
```

assuming you have already named the route, i think this still works as well:

```
return Redirect::intended('/foo');
```

---

UPDATE:
try this:
retrieve the requested URI :

```
$uri = Request::path(); // Implemented in Lumen
```

then redirect to the requested URI :

```
return redirect($uri);
```

this could work !!

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately, I've already tried to solve the problem this way.

Comment: try the Request::path();

Answer (score 2):

Indeed looking at the source code of Lumen it is not implemented:
https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/5.0/src/Http/Redirector.php

Your options are:

1. Check Laravel's (Symfony's?) implementation and put it into your own code
2. Write completely your own implementation – one super simple way of doing it would be store the request URL in a session, redirect to the login page and when the user successfully logs in retrieve the URL from the session and redirect him

Comment: Thank you, I've already thought of that but I wanted to be sure it wasn't implemented before I would do it myself. :)