# FatalErrorException when building route

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I try to make a route in controller to another route:

```
return Redirect::to('build/'.$this->index);
```

Also tried:

```
return Redirect::away('build/'.$this->index);
```

It gave me error like:

> FatalErrorException in 421450c53c0b66d6ec46800df8ef0257 line 3:
>   Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse as array

Line 3 is:

```
<?php if(isset($data['view']) && $data['view'] == "newBuilding"): ?>
```

But the only solution that worked was:

```
header('Location: '.URL::to('build/'.$this->index)); dd("Moved 302.");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work :`return Redirect::to('build/{$this->index}');` , you must use the curly braces to pass parameters.

Comment: Same thing :( Can't find anything that helps. I've tried even setting header() in RedirectResponse, but it caused even more bugs than now

Comment: what version of laravel are you using ?

Comment: I am using Laravel 5 atm

Comment: Check this thread, maybe you may find something, this guy used a middleware to redirect, this is how he set it up :

Comment: Check this thread, maybe you may find something, this guy used a middleware to redirect, this is how he set it up (middlewares are implemented in the same way wether it's lumen or laravel) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29963383/redirect-to-intended-url-lumen/29964159#29964159, and here's the doc :http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/middleware